# Is it possible to deselect a particular row in Aggrid?

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

I am trying to deselect a specific row in aggrid.
I have gone through the documentation but couldn't find one.

```
  gridOptions.api.deselectAll();
```

This is what I am using to deselect all rows.But is there any way to deselect specific rows in Aggrid

I tried so many ways.Please help me to get through this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the row node api to deselect a node.

Based on [docs](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-row-node/#rowNodeMethods) -

> **setSelected(newValue: boolean, clearSelection: boolean)**
> Select (or deselect) the node. newValue=true for selection, newValue=false
> for deselection. If selecting, then passing true for clearSelection
> will select the node exclusively (i.e. NOT do multi select). If doing
> deselection, clearSelection has no impact.

You need to first get the id of the node you want to deselect and do something like -

```
const node = gridOptions.api.getRowNode(id);
node.setSelected(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

ag-Grid doesn't have toggling for the single row selection out of the box. That's just my understanding based on official docs, I sure can be wrong about this.

So for the multiple row selection it's easy and supported out of the box:

you just need to set `rowMultiSelectWithClick` to `true` and `rowSelection` to  `'multiple'` in the gridOptions (or whatever you call the config object).

For the single row select/deselect I've come up with the following ([working plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/3Bsh6P7gApIbPWne?preview)):

```
const gridOptions = {


columnDefs: [
    { field: 'name' },
    { field: 'continent' },
    { field: 'language' },
  ],
  defaultColDef: {
    flex: 1,
    resizable: true,
  },
  rowData: rowData,

  // here i'm just checking for the right selection mode
  // and firing my custom little function when the row is clicked
  onRowClicked: this.rowSelection === 'single' && toggleRowSelection,

  rowMultiSelectWithClick: true,
  rowSelection: 'single'
};

let selectedRow = null;

// this function is just for keeping track of selected row id
// and programmatically deselecting the row by doing node.setSelected(false)

function toggleRowSelection({ node }) {
  if (selectedRow !== node.id) {
    selectedRow = node.id;
  } else {
    selectedRow = null;
    node.setSelected(false);
  }
}
```